# Access Master page control from content page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to access master page linkbutton from content page, content page contains iframe, and i want to call click event of that linkbutton using javascript. 
so, anyone can help me??
I have already tried followings,

```
var a=document.getElementById('<%=lblMaster.ClientID %>');
var v = $find("Name").get_Text();
```

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You mean it is an asp.net application.

Please use `window.parent.$("#Name").text();`